# Can I short live Rc and Rh terminals together as R?

Tags: wiring

I have separated HVAC system with 24V on Rc and Heating system with 24V on Rh. The nest thermostat 2020 has only R terminal. The voltage difference between Rc and RH is about 2V. Can I short Rc and Rh together, put into R terminal?

Comment: Do you want the heating and the cooling to come on at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

### You need to return it and get a different 'stat

The thermostat you have is a refresh of the Nest "E" model, and thus is a stripped-down version that doesn't support more sophisticated systems, such as your two-transformer system, or multi-stage systems of any sort for that matter.  You will need to return it and get a full-fledged 3rd generation Nest, or some other thermostat for that matter, that has separate Rh and Rc terminals.